# printing 2 dimentional array in python with ANSI formatting codes, without iterating each element

Tags: python, arrays, ansi-escape

I am writing program where each character element of array is checked against certain condition. If condition is true , the element should formatted in bold and color.

program is something as below:

```
arr = [['F','O','R','S','T'],
       ['A','B','C','D','E'],
       ['M','N','P','Q','R']]

for row in arr:
    print (row)

for row in arr:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        #its just sample condition, actual condition would be different
        if row[i] == 'F' or row[i] == 'A' or row[i] == 'M': 
            row[i] = '\033[31m'+row[i]+'\x1b[0m'

print("\nUpdated Array: printed by iterating each element")
for row in arr:
    for column in row:
            print (column, end=" ")
    print("\n")

print("\nUpdated Array: printed without iterating each element")
for row in arr:
    print (row)
```

**output is as below:**

['F', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'T']

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

['M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R']

Updated Array: printed by iterating each element

**F** O R S T

**A** B C D E

**M** N P Q R

Updated Array: printed without iterating each element

['\x1b[31mF\x1b[0m', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'T']

['\x1b[31mA\x1b[0m', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

['\x1b[31mM\x1b[0m', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R']

---

Is there any way to directly print array as below without iterating array

[**'F'**, 'O', 'R', 'S', 'T']

[**'A'**, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

[**'M'**, 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R']

Comment: the problem is that string should be output from `print()`,for example `a = '\033[31m'+'A'+'\x1b[0m'`,if you type `a` in python console,it will output `'\x1b[31mA\x1b[0m'` but if you type `print(a)` it will give you bold colored A as output, now when you `print(arr)` in your case it will print the list

Answer (score 0):

You can make the array as single string and then print the string

```
new = ''
for row in arr:
    for col in row:
        #its just sample condition, actual condition would be different
        if col == 'F' or col == 'A' or col == 'M': 
         new += (' \033[31m'+ col +'\x1b[0m ')
        else:
          new+=(' '+ col)
    new+=('\n')
```

and then print the `new`

Output:

```
 F O R S T
 A B C D E
 M N P Q R
```